# elseif checks if the condition is false?

Tags: php

For example in the following code...

```
$a=1;
if($a == 1)
echo 'good'...

else
echo 'bad'...
```

if $a not equal 1, it will go to else, but...

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
if($a == 1)
echo 'good'...

elseif($b==2)
echo 'bad'...
```

The elseif only evaluates if $b is equal to 2, or it also too evaluates that $a is different from 1 as if elseif were an else?

In other words... Does elseif only check the condition that is put in it or does it also put the one that is not fulfilled in the if?

Comment: The `elseif` will only be checked if the `if` did not match.  If that's not what you want, remove the `else` part and just use another `if`.

Comment: Protip: never use if statements without curly bracket blocks. Explicitly enclose what you need to happen in `{...}` so that never run into hilarious bugs where you just added a line and _completely changed the meaning of your code_.

Answer (score 0):

The *elseif* statement in PHP only checks the condition that is specified within it. It does not automatically include the condition from the preceding *if* statement.

In your example, if $a is equal to 1, the first *if* statement will be *true*, and it will execute the code block inside the *if* statement, which will output 'good'. The *elseif* statement will not be evaluated in this case.

If $a is not equal to 1, the first *if* statement will be false, and it will skip the code block inside the *if* statement. Then, the *elseif* statement will be evaluated. If $b is equal to 2, the *elseif* condition will be true, and it will execute the code block inside the *elseif* statement, which will output 'bad'.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct.  It certainly DOES include the condition from the preceding *if* statement.  It's just the negation of that condition, but you can't say it isn't included.

Answer (score 0):

1. First php checks if condition.
2. If condition is true then executes
   code block inside the if statement then ignores all elseif and else
   statements after that go to point 4.
3. If condition is false
   `3.1. Check if there is elseif condition.`
   `3.2. If there is else if condition go to point 2 and repeat process.`
   `3.3. If there is no elseif condition check if there is else condition.`
   `3.4. If there is else run else block then go to point 4.`
   `3.5. If there is no else block go to point 4.`
4. Execute next line of code.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
if($a == 1)
echo 'good'...

elseif($b==2)
echo 'bad'...
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
if($a == 1) {
   echo 'good'...
}
else {
   if($b==2) {
      echo 'bad'...
   }
}
```

Writing it like that makes the nesting more clear.